# enable_if struct definition and default template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

According to the definition of enable_if struct :

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

I am wondering how

```
template<class T>
T foo(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0) 
{
    return t;
}
```

particularly :

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type
```

could be invoked without specified type T, in case `std::is_integral<T>::value` equal `true`. In this case the specialization of std::enable_if will be called and in this definition there is no default template parameter.

Is it due to deduce template parameter mechanism ? If yes why specified a default paramater for not specialization definition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit cryptic, but as I understand it:

> I am wondering how `...` could be invoked without specified type T

1. It won't; The `foo` and `enable_if` templates will only be instantiated when the user needs their instantiations (implicitly or explicitly) *with specific values for `T`*. So `T` is always specified.
2. Default template parameters are only featured on "base" template definitions (ie. *not* specializations). That is why you only see it on the first declaration of `enable_if`. However, they affect all specializations (basically, if you instantiate `enable_if<X>`, the compiler sees you have not provided one of the arguments for the base template and tries to match all specializations with parameter list `<X, void>`).

BTW the second template argument is used to get a different type out of `enable_if` than `void`:

```
std:enable_if<1, int>::type f();
```

would be just `int f()`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `enable_if` template is to *remove* function templates from the overload set. By itself, your example is not terribly useful, except that it will refuse instantiation for non-integral types with a compiler error. But if you also wrote a second overload, for example with the reverse condition, then `foo(1)` and `foo(1.0)` would both only find one single viable overload and there's no ambiguity.

In fact, think about this again: While deducing the arguments for `foo(1.0)`, the first version (the one you wrote) will actually be erroneous, since there is no member type `::type`. However, this is *not* a hard compiler error, but only a so-called "substitution failure" – and that is *not* an error. It simply removes the entire template from consideration.

As a side note, there's a related use for `enable_if` in *class* templates to help disambiguate speciali­za­tions, also using default arguments. It looks something like `template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<some_condition>::type> ...`

Comment: I think OP already knows all this. The (2.) paragraph in the other answer is what they wanted to know, I believe.